# Prove that $Ax=b$ has a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra

Could you help me please and give some tips on how should I prove it (show it).

Prove that Sol(A,b) of quadratic system of linear equations with n×n-Matrix:

$A =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & .. & 0& 0\\ 
1 & 1 & -1 &  0& .. & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 &  ..&  0& 0\\ 
.. & .. & .. & .. & .. & .. &..\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & .. & 1 & -1\\ 
0 &  0&  0&  0& .. & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

for $n\geq 1$ and all b from  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ has only ONE solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well the row vectors of $A$ are clearly linearly independent. Hence $A$ is invertible and so $Ax = b$ has only one solution.

Comment: What is a *quadratic system* of linear equations? Does that just mean linear equations with same number of unknowns as equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the system $\mathbf A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ to have a unique solution, where $\mathbf A$ is the tridiagonal matrix you have, one way of proceeding is to show that $\mathbf A$ is nonsingular. Letting $a_n=\det\mathbf A_n$, where $n$ is the size of $\mathbf A$, you can establish the recursion relation

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$

with initial conditions $a_1=|1|=1$ and $a_2=\begin{vmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{vmatrix}=2$, through [cofactor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) on the last column and last row of the matrix. You should be able to recognize a [certain famous sequence](http://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/42-3/quartcahill03_2004.pdf)...

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. May I ask you: is there any other way, how I can prove it, without determinant?

Comment: @Lissa: PZZ's comment to your question hints to another method.